# If a certain criteria is met in a cell, I Need to take a "snapshot/copy" of another cell containing a formula, and paste it as value in a third cell

Tags: excel, vba

Summary: If a certain criteria is met in a cell (b5,B6, B7,...), I Need to take a "snapshot/copy" of another cell containing a formula (let's say D3), , and paste it as value in a third cell (let's say C5, C6, C7,...) and so forth.

Example:

If B5 is different than "", Then copy value of cell D3 and paste it (value) in C5.
if B6 is different than "", Then copy value of cell D3 and paste it (value) in C6....

Value in D3 is constantly changing due to a formula, so I need to store the value in it as it was when I entered the values in Cells B5,B6,B7, etc so that I can later do some analysis/calculations with it.

Thank you and please let me know if more detail is needed.

[sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dj5X.png)

Comment: Use the worksheet_change or worksheet_calculate event, depending on whether the changing values are being manually changed, or are the result of formulas.

Comment: the cell that's being changed is due to a formula.

Comment: Then you'll need to look at  `worksheet_calculate` - lots of examples here